# Issue in passing string in Request Body

Tags: java, json, rest-assured

I am facing an issue while making a request body to do an API call in Java.

***Required Body***

```
{
    "id" : [1,2]
}
```

I have an integer array with me lets say `arr`, I am creating the request something like:-

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("id",Arrays.toString(arr));
String stringBody = jsonObject.toJSONString();
RequestSpecification specification = RestAssured.with();
specification.body(stringBody);
Response response = specification.post(endpoint);
```

What it actually does is make the request body as something like below.

```
{
    "id" : "[1,2]"
}
```

As it sends the value as String so my server throws an error, `Expected a list of items but got type \"unicode\"`.

Can somebody help me in here. How do I send it in raw format instead of String.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
jsonObject.put("id",Arrays.asList(arr));
```

to build the json body.

Comment: This won't work, since it will pass the address not the value `[1,2]`

Comment: @nikky can you try this> `String stringBody = jsonObject.toString();`

Comment: `jsonObject.toJSONString();` != `jsonObject.toString();` see the difference.